# One route, two valid payloads in Hapi.js with Joi

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js, joi

I'm trying to validate two different payload schemas on the same route. The two valid options are:

```
validate: {
  payload: {
    email: Joi.string().required(),
    password: Joi.string().required()
  }
}
```

and

```
validate: {
  payload: {
    token: Joi.string().required()
  }
}
```

I have tried using a combination of the `and` and `or` functions which gets very close but it allows all three to be passed as the payload:

```
validate: {
  payload: Joi.object().keys({
    email: Joi.string().required(),
    password: Joi.string().required(),
    token: Joi.string().required()
  }).and('email', 'password').or('token', 'email', 'password')
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, I worked it out. I needed to use `xor` with just one of the two dependent:

```
validate: {
  payload: Joi.object().keys({
    email: Joi.string(),
    password: Joi.string(),
    token: Joi.string()
  }).and('email', 'password').xor('token', 'password')
}
```